# On Bourbaki's "Integration" - Why/What/How to read it

Tags: integration, measure-theory, math-history

I have a question concerning the **Bourbaki**'s book on **integration**.

Whenever I find them referenced (in answers on this site as well), it looks like they aged more than volumes of the same series on other topics. Also, it looks like they were criticised from the outset (e.g. see Halmos' comment from page 11 of [this chapter](http://www.tau.ac.il/~corry/publications/articles/pdf/bourbaki-structures.pdf)).

Thus, the questions:

1. **why?**
   *Is there a problem in the entire approach to the topic?

   What was problematic in it?*
2. How sensible is to read them right now, beyond historical purposes?
   *What should somebody have in mind when reading them?

   How shoud somebody read them?

   Given the answer to question (1), what should be taken, and what should be dismissed?*

Thank you as always for any feedback.

PS: Moreover, right now, *are there serious problems with the terminology? Is it outdated?*

Comment: **To the Moderators:** I am not sure about the tag `math-history`, because this is not really about the history of math. There could be seen a relation to it, though. Hence, my decision to put it there.

Comment: Your 1 might be completely answered [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bourbaki#Appraisal_of_the_Bourbaki_perspective), note especially the choice to develop integration only on locally compact Hausdorff spaces, which makes Bourbaki unable to come to terms with most of modern probability theory.

Comment: @Did Thanks a lot for the comment and the link! From it: *"Taking the case of locally compact measure spaces as fundamental focuses the presentation on Radon measures and leads to an approach to measurable functions that is cumbersome, especially from the viewpoint of probability theory."* Thus, Schwartz's "Radon measures on arbitrary topological spaces and cylindrical measures" should suffer the same problems, right?

Comment: The closest thing to a guide I can find is this https://www.ma.utexas.edu/mp_arc/c/11/11-169.pdf or this https://www.ma.utexas.edu/mp_arc/c/08/08-234.pdf and this review http://www.math.tu-dresden.de/sto/schilling/sources/reviews/bourbaki.pdf says " It was probability theory that showed that Bourbaki’s point of view of Radon integrals on locally compact spaces was inadequate; as a reaction Chapter 9 was written as a general ‘fix’ and to cater for the needs of probability theory" so apparently if you take into account chapter 9 you can make up for it and get what looks like a better approach.

Comment: @bolbteppa Thanks a lot. Very nice links!

Comment: This book is a bit crazy, e.g. the first theorem relies on Hahn-Banach, if you want to create a chat room about it we could think up something here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar and do it slowly on the side over time